# Where to save commonly used methods?

Tags: java, cucumber

There's a couple of methods that are used multiple times in my Step Definitions, for example: `theUserSearchesForKeyInCollection(String key, String collection)`.

What is best practice with regards to the location of these methods? Do you trust your IDE to be able to find them for you (as in IDEA Ctrl-B) or do you do something else?

What I'm doing now is have that method in one of the Step Definition files used, which means they're "kind of missing" in other Step Definitions where its corresponding Feature file does mention it. I'm not entirely happy about that, so I'm hoping for something better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbeknownst to me, the question is already giving me the answer. After all, it seems Cucumber will find the method even when it's in another file. So, I've made a class `CommonSteps` and put it in there. As I go, it will probably be put under `CommonSearchSteps` should the former grow beyond my liking.

Even worse, it's documented on the Cucumber site under [Step Organization](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/step-organization/#grouping-step-definitions) and not doing so is listed as an [Anti-pattern](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/anti-patterns/#feature-coupled-step-definitions).